# android simulator crashes when using intent

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android studio, I'm using java to write my application.
I found that when I use intent to make the page jump from a page call `PhotosActivity` to another page call `AndroidTabLayoutActivity` was failed,I have no idea with what is going on.The android simulator does't give me any error massage and it just close the application automatically.

the code of calling intent:

```
if (!error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Offer successfully inserted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Jump to the AndroidTabLayoutActivity page
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            PhotosActivity.this,
                            AndroidTabLayoutActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
```

The code of AndroidTabLayoutActivity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Tab for Photos
    TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
    photospec.setIndicator("Photos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
    Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);
    photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

    //there is still some others tab in here

    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that my code have run into the `if(!error)` ,and I have try to intent to another page,it success. What I want to say is the `intent` work on the others page but not `AndroidTabLayoutActivity`.

Comment: have you checked the logcat?Identify the cause of issue from the logcat

Comment: oh, sorry that is the logcat of the others apps....I still get nothing error with this code

Comment: check your logout with `NO Filter`

Comment: @TejasPandya Thank you for suggestion, finally I see the error, but I still have no idea with how to handle it...

Comment: `E/AudioFlinger:not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296`,`E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?`, `E/IAudioFlinger: createRecord returned error -12`,`E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12`

Comment: `E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.`,`E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.`

Comment: here is all the error I get

Answer (score 0):

```
You have using getApplicationContext() in this toast method

Replace with activity context, i am sure your code is working fine   

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Offer successfully inserted.", 
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 Use like this 

 Toast.makeText(PhotosActivity.this, "Offer successfully inserted.", 
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is no any particular error log. We have to backtrack all the possibilities .

1. First of all replace your toast with this.

   `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Offer successfully inserted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
2. After that ensure that you've declared your `AndroidTabLayoutActivity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file
3. In your `AndroidTabLayoutActivity` Cooment out all your code  and check its working ? if yes than problem is in `AndroidTabLayoutActivity`. reply me with whats working for you

Comment: I'm sorry sir, the toast look same with my original code `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Offer successfully inserted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: for no.2, yes I have declared `AndroidTabLayoutActivity` in my manifest. no3, yes, all of my code is work in `AndroidTabLayoutActivity`

Comment: @QiuXue  double verify your xml code in main.xml and I doubt that may be your TabHost is creating issuie . so also check that by commenting out